# Convert plain text password in mysql database to bcrypt encrypted password

Tags: php, encryption, mysqli, bcrypt

I have mysql database with around 500 records. There is a column `password` which is currently containing plain text passwords.

I want to covert these passwords to `encrypted with bcrypt`. How can I do it from **phpmyadmin** ?

*Second appended question* : what will be login page coding to check this encrypted password and let member get in ? ( I am using mysqli)

Comment: phpmyadmin is probably to only view your mysql db and not process any php code on it. you need to do this through a php script

Comment: @Shubhank ohhh...ok Can u elaborate with some example coding?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, backup your db... Then you have to do something like this...

Not knowing your app I can just make an example, this probably won't work in your current production code.

```
$servername = "YOUR_SERVER";
$username = "YOUR_USERNAME";
$password = "YOUR_PASSWORD";
$dbname = "YOUR_DB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, password FROM your_table";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$newPasswords = [];

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $newPasswords[] = ["id" => $row["id"], "newPass" = "YOUR_PASSWORD_ENCRYPTED_WITH_BCRYPY"];  
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

foreach($newPasswords as $user) {
$sql = "UPDATE your_table SET password = $user["newPass"] WHERE id = $user["id"]";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
}

$conn->close();
```

After this, you can change your app to login the user taking care of the new encrypted password. To encrypt with `bcrypt` in PHP look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Again **remember to backup your database before any operation!**